# How to store images in SQL Server for regular data sync process?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to store image data in SQL Server along with data sync with master database.

I explored few options on many blogs and most of them say it's always better to store an image URL instead of a full image. Even I agree with this as it reduces the load on SQL Server engine. But this approach is not easy if I need to do data sync regularly.

So I am thinking of storing the images as varbinary(max). Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently true that IIS serves up images from the file system (ie from a URL) much faster than images can be retrieved from Sql Server and then rendered in code however it does work ok. We store images in a varbinary(max) column as we cannot store them in the file system for similar reasons to you.